# Meteor helpers returning a useable class

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

Meteor noob here, trying to get the hang of templates. So I have this set in the JS:

```
Session.set('activeSection', 'start');

Template.sectionContainer.helpers = ({
    "isActive": function() {
        return (Session.get("activeSection") === 'start') ? "active" : "nope";
    }
});
```

and then have:

```
<template name="sectionContainer">
    <section class="{{isActive}}"></section>
</template>
```

However, I am not getting the active/nope classes as I'd expect. `sectionContainer` is nested inside another template, if that's of any importance. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here, what am I doing wrong?

It works just fine using the the deprecated syntax:

```
Template.sectionContainer.isActive = function() {
    return (Session.get("activeSection") === 'start') ? "active" : "nope";
}
```

Even running `Template.sectionContainer.helpers.isActive()` from the console returns the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this works:

```
Template.sectionContainer.isActive = function() {
   return (Session.get("activeSection") === 'start') ? "active" : "nope";
}
```

then in new syntax it will be :

```
Template.sectionContainer.helpers({
    isActive: function() {
        return (Session.get("activeSection") === 'start') ? "active" : "nope";
    }
});
```

Comment: Apparently I got the syntax down then, but I have to be doing something wrong since a simple translation of old -> new syntax is breaking the code.

Comment: isActive: function() {
        if(Session.get("activeSection") == 'start') return "active";
return "nope";
    }

Comment: If this doesn't work then there is something wrong with session

Comment: It does not work. Running "Session.get("activeSection")" in the console shows the right value though. :/

Comment: Maybe you got this helper signed to another template than you use it in - Template.<template>.helpers. I fnot then push this to some repository and I'll see what might be the problem

Comment: https://github.com/mastastealth/helperTest - I created the simplest test case I could, exhibiting the same problem

Comment: Hehe its template...helpers({ not Template...helpers = ({

Comment: *sigh* Thank you. I knew it was gonna be something stupid. I'm gonna mark yours as the answer, for helping me narrow it down. xD Thanks!

Comment: Haha glad it helped :D and by the way I did it in my answer ;p

Answer (score 1):

You should use it like:

```
Template.sectionContainer.helpers({
    isActive: function() {
        return Session.equals("activeSection", "start") ? "active" : "nope";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is certainly a better syntax for the conditional, but does not solve my rendering problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm, have you got something like: <template name="name1"><template name="name2"></template></template> ??

Comment: Not within the same file. I use <template name="sectionContainer">...</template> (which is in its own HTML file) inside another like so: <template name="layout> {{> sectionContainer}} </template>